How to make my primary language appear as the first option in Install4j
I have an install4j project with the following configuration:

As a result, I get the following window:

My primary language is Ukrainian, so I expect that:

In combo-box will be selected Ukrainian. How can I achieve that?

How can I increase the window size? All text must fit without being truncated.



Can you share the top of the installation log where the system properties are printed? The log file is in the /tmp directory until the "Install files" action runs, then it is in the <installation directory>/.install4j directory. As for the size problem, please contact support@ej-technologies.com for a build where this is fixed for such large font sizes.
